# Check file name before deletion (windows Batch)

Tags: batch-file, text-files, delete-file

Is there a way using Windows Batch to read a txt file list of file names. And if the name is present in the list to preserve that file but. If the file name is not found in the txt list that it is deleted.

I namely trying to filter out a horde of temporary files automatically generated by not cleaned out by AutoCAD.

The reason for reading a txt list would allow me to add or delete file names for processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible with Windows batch. Assuming you got a list of files `FilesToKeep.txt` with filenames like this:

```
WillBeKept.txt
WillAlsoBeKept.doc
```

in the same directory as the following batch script:

```
@echo OFF
pushd "%~dp0"
set "PathToCleanup=E:\Temp\Test"
for /F "tokens=*" %%F in ('dir /S/B/A-D %PathToCleanup%\*.*') do (
     findstr /S %%~nxF FilesToKeep.txt >NUL || del /Q "%%F" )
```

This script loops through all files in `PathToCleanup` and if a filename is not present in `FilesToCleanup.txt` then the file will be deleted.